# Pycharm cannot find module (used to work) when clicking the `run` button

Tags: python, pycharm, python-unittest

I used to be able to run Python unittests and things worked fine but all of a sudden things stopped? I attribute it to installing the cython speedup for the debugger but I don't know how to prove it. I say that it might be the cython speedup because the test immediately after installing it was the start of the `ModuleNotFoundError`.

---

Folder structure

```
Top_folder
  - module
    - submodule1
    - submodule2
    - __init__.py
  - tests
    - test1
    - test2
    - __init__.py
```

---

The contents of `test1` are along the lines of

```py
from module.submodule1.foo import bar
```

When I run it, pressing the built-in run button, it screams at me saying:

> `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module.submodule1'`

---

## What I've tried

1. Mark sources root. I marked `module` as my sources root.
2. Mark `tests` as my tests root.
3. Deleted the `.idea` folder.
4. Invalidating the caches.
5. Deleting my Conda environment.

---

Comment: How are you running the test? Is it pytest or are the tests just regular Python modules?

Comment: They are `unittest`s.

Comment: Is `Top_folder` a project root or a directory inside the project root? In the last case - mark the `Top_folder` as the source root. Ctrl/Cmd+click "module" in `from module.submodule1.foo import bar` - does it bring you to the expected location? You can also insert `import module; print(module)` as the first line in a test script to verify the correct module is imported in runtime.

Comment: > does it bring you to the expected location? Hmm, I can't seem to mark anything as the project root. I can only mark things as the sources root.... Interestingly enough, when I add some code under the `__main__` in `foo`, it is able to run without any issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid pycharm changed the default test runner. This damn IDE is sometimes such a headache.

```
1) Open up settings
2) Tools
3) Python Integrated tools
4) Testing. Change to whatever runner you want as the default
```

Note, you'll have to delete any other test runners to get it to build the correct configs